# SQL Query - join help (Getting lots of results)

Tags: sql, join

I have a student table and a company table.

**Student Table**

id

fname

lname

company_id

**Company Table**

company_id

name

type

I want to output the student table data and then join the company data so the company id will reference the company name and industry.

**Here's the query I'm running**

```
SELECT id, fname, lname, company.company_id, name, type
FROM  `student` 
INNER JOIN company ON student.company_id
ORDER BY type
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT student_id, student_fname, student_lname, company.company_id, company_name, industry
FROM  `student` 
INNER JOIN company ON student.company_id=company.company_id
ORDER BY industry
```

Specify columns for both tables when you join them.Without them you do a CROSS JOIN,thats is every row in A is associated with all rows in B.

Answer (score 1):

It should be `ON student.company_id = company.company_id`

Other than that it looks fine.

```
SELECT student_id, student_fname, student_lname, company.company_id, company_name, industry
FROM  `student` 
INNER JOIN company ON student.company_id = company.company_id
ORDER BY industry
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting what is known as a Cartesian Product A.K.A a Cross-Join.

The join needs to specify a matching column that exists in both tables. In your case, that is the `company id`. The solution is on the line:

`INNER JOIN company ON student.company_id`

This line should instead be:

`INNER JOIN company ON student.company_id=company.company_id`

That will avoid the cross-join you are experiencing.

See [this link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-cartesian-joins.htm) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can also write:

```
INNER JOIN company USING (company_id)
```